# Go back 'n' lines in file using Stream.lines

Tags: java, file-io, java-stream

I need to build an application which scans through a large amount of files. These files contain blocks with some data about a sessions, in which each line has a different value. E.g.: "=ID: 39487".

At that point I have that line, but the problem I now face is that I need the value n lines above that ID. I was thinking about an Iterator but it only has forward methods. I also thought about saving the results in a List but that defies the reason to use Stream and some files are huge so that would cause memory problems.

I was wondering if something like this is possible using the Stream API (Files)? Or perhaps a better question, is there a better way to approach this?

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(file.getName()));
Iterator<String> search = lines.iterator();
```

Comment: What exactly is the processing that you need to do? You already have a `Stream` and can collect it into a `List`. If some files are huge, you are possibly looking out for some parallel processing with distributed systems?

Comment: Can this be solved by iterating through the entire file backwards? Or do you also need the "forward" direction?

Comment: I need a value n lines above, and then some more below (using that value).

Comment: @nullpointer I'm not sure I understand what you ask.

Comment: What you describe sounds like a form of ring buffer, i.e. you put each line onto the buffer and if it is full then the oldest line gets evicted. Once you find a line that matches you process the entire content of that ring buffer as needed. - Using the stream api you still could do it in `forEach()` - imo putting data into a buffer wouldn't really defy the use of streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't arbitrarily read backwards and forwards through the file with the same reader (no matter if you're using streams, iterators, or a plain `BufferedReader`.)

If you need:

- `m` lines before a given line
- `n` lines after the given line
- You don't know the value of `m` and `n` in advance, until you reach that line

...then you essentially have three options:

- Read the whole file once, keep it in memory, and then your task is trivial (but this uses the most memory.)
- Read the whole file once, mark the line numbers that you need, then do a second pass where you extract the lines you require.
- Read the whole file once, storing some form of metadata about line lengths as you go, then use a `RandomAccessFile` to extract the specific bits you need without having to read the whole file again.

I'd suggest given the files are huge, the second option here is probably the most realistic. The third will probably give you better performance, but will require much more in the way of development effort.

As an alternative if you can guarantee that both `n` and `m` are below a certain value, and that value is a reasonable size - you could also just keep a certain number of lines in a buffer as you're processing the file, and read through that buffer when you need to read lines "backwards".

Answer (score 0):

Try my library. [abacus-util](https://github.com/landawn/AbacusUtil)

```
try(Reader reader = new FileReader(yourFile)) {
    StreamEx.of(reader)
        .sliding(n, n, ArrayList::new)
        .filter(l -> l.get(l.size() - 1).contains("=ID: 39487"))
        ./* then do your work */
}
```

No matter how big your file is. as long as `n` is small number, not millions